# How to inform the app users to turn on their WiFi or 4G

Tags: ios, notifications

I am new developer and I am developing my first ios application. Would you please advice me how to inform the users to turn on their WiFi or any other type of internet signal? I mean my app requires internet signal and if I haven't turned it on, it even does not load the first view. I think it is crashing, because nothing is happening. Would you please tell me how can I inform the users, by small notification maybe.I use something similar when I require GPS signal in the second view controll:

```
  let alertC : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Iwin", message: "UserLocation Not Updated turn on your gps", preferredStyle: .alert)
  let okAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "oK", style: .default, handler: { (okActn) in
            print("User pressed ok")
        })
```

But I do not know how to load a similar notification when the user opens the app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

*"I am new developer"*, check [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) for pods installation.

You can do something similar to this:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let reachability = Reachability()!
        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }

        return true
    }
```

ViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged),name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,object: reachability)
    do{
    try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
        print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have installed cocoapods before in my app

Comment: Anwer is updated.
Please, add a comment if you still have a problem with the solution

Comment: would you advise me how to install reachability for swift 3, because mine is for the previous version. I tried with 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3' but it isnt working

Comment: if (pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3') didn't work, just let it (pod 'ReachabilitySwift') without specifying the version, it should automatically install the latest version.

Comment: ok I installed it, but it seems that there is a problem with the code

Comment: in this line:  try reachability.startNotifier()
I get an error which is constant reachability used before it is initialized

Comment: I will check it... and adding edits if needed
what is your version of Swift? is it 3?

Comment: Sure thank you, it is very important for me it is swift 3 right